# UICollectionView weird animation (ghost cell, flash) on reload data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Hello as you can see in the [video link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DttM9mxB-I&feature=youtu.be) below when I reload the data, for a frame something happens and some ghost cells appear and disappear, it's like a weird animation... Is it because of using reusable cells? and if it is, is it preventable cause that's not so pretty and it seems to cause a bit of frame drop with use of CATransition animation (not shown in the video). Any help would be appreciated.

[Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pITJ-KEJNH4_nHN0y5yXpEggoPSEiaMW)

[Video Youtube Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DttM9mxB-I&feature=youtu.be)

*** EDIT ***

Seems the video is not processed by google drive, sorry you gotta download it first to watch it.

Added [Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DttM9mxB-I&feature=youtu.be) for convenience

Comment: Don't know what was with the downvote yet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I Found the answer myself thanks to all the unnecessary downvotes:

The first solution was to use 
`collectionView.reloadItems(at: collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems)`
but that still caused some problem and flicker stuff.

Some other said to use `layoutIfNeeded()` after that, yet that did not help.

The Solution I Found was to use `func reloadSections(_ sections: IndexSet)`

so when I use `collectionView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer:0))` (in my case it is the first section) The animation will happen smooth and perfect.